# DataTables highlighting dosen´t work

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my [link](http://live.datatables.net/beyebec/6/edit) to a live example: Can you tell me, why the `highlighting` of the rows and columns do not work?

Comment: Thanks 'Satpal' now i have changed it. But the rows still not  'highlighting'. Just the columns.   http://live.datatables.net/beyebec/8/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in CSS only without the need of any script by using these definitions:

```css
 #example tbody tr.even:hover, #example tbody tr.even td.highlighted {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tbody tr.odd:hover, #example tbody tr.odd td.highlighted {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.even:hover {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.even:hover td.sorting_1 {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.even:hover td.sorting_2 {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.even:hover td.sorting_3 {
     background-color :yellow;
}
 #example tr.odd:hover {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.odd:hover td.sorting_1 {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.odd:hover td.sorting_2 {
     background-color: yellow;
}
 #example tr.odd:hover td.sorting_3 {
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

Yep, that's a lot! You need to set the #id for your tables id.

[Here is an updated BIN](http://live.datatables.net/vefirep/1/edit)

Or, if you just want to highlight rows without coloring for special cases like odd/even/sorting you can wrap this down to this simple rule:

```
#example tbody tr:hover{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Look [here](http://live.datatables.net/yijiyex/1/edit)

If you want both column and row highlighting you need to combine @SPECs answer and mine.

[Like so](http://live.datatables.net/fulocow/1/edit)

Comment: Great CSS-only solution! When using Bootstrap, row highlighting doesn't seem to be working for the shaded rows when using the `table-striped` class, but works for the white/unshaded rows. Any work-arounds for that?

Comment: I can't edit my original comment, so here's the work-around I found: `tbody tr:hover td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd):hover td { background-color: yellow; }`

Answer (score 0):

just change highlighted to highlight

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready( function () { 
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bSortClasses": false
  });

   oTable.$('td').hover( function() {
     console.log('hi');
        var iCol = $('td', this.parentNode).index(this) % 5;
        console.log(iCol);
     $('td:nth-child('+(iCol+1)+')', oTable.$('tr')).addClass( 'highlight' );
    }, function() {
        oTable.$('td.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    } );

} );
```